# Xml Dom library with unit tests

Tags: java, .net, xml, unit-testing, dom

Googled for a Xml Dom open source library that ships with unit tests, but could not find any. Are there any dom libraries, java or .net that have unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Xerces certainly includes a bunch of tests; look in the [SVN repository](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xerces/java/).  I expect that other libraries do as well.  (I cannot imagine how you could develop an XML DOM implementation without some kind of unit / regression test suite.)

Perhaps you are looking in the wrong place for unit tests, or your criteria for what constitutes a "unit test" is too restrictive.

Comment: they don't seem to be using traditional unit testing libraries like JUnit.

Comment: they probably don't think that traditional unit testing would work for them.

Comment: you are right, I was looking at source code distributions, and it does not contain tests, but code in the repository does contain test and in dom4j for example they use testng.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure whether by "DOM" you mean "pure W3C DOM" or DOM-like libraries in general, but [XOM](http://xom.nu/) has very complete unit test coverage, based on JUnit.